# Nodereference empty when internationalization enabled

Tags: drupal, cck

I just enabled the translation module and the i18n module. One of my content types has a node reference field, and after translating the page, the node reference dropdown is empty. It works fine for English (default lang) but no other languages.

Answer (score 1):

nodereference will only refer to nodes of the same language.  You must create nodes in the other languages in order to make them accessible to your field.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I have two nodes translated now, both with menu items set up and still nothing in the nodereference dropdown for the corresponding language. I've tried clearing the Drupal cache as well. Any ideas?